# How do you search ! in man sed?

Tags: shell, quoting, man, less

You cannot search ! directly because it puts process behind. 
For instance, you cannot search ! in `sed man`.

How can you search ! in man?

Comment: If you are using `less` as man pager then `/\!`.

Comment: You can escape it by `\ ` = `\!`

Comment: @jimmij Good! I use normally less but now I used man and got confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man` itself is a tool to format manual pages, not to browse them. The tool you use to browse the man pages is a [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager). The default pager on most systems is [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)).

In less, when you press `/` or `?` to search, a few characters have a special meaning if you type them at the beginning of the search expression. The exclamation mark is one of them. To avoid `!` having a special meaning, put a backslash before it. It is very common for backslash to mean “interpret the next character literally”.

So to search for an exclamation mark, press `/\!` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

```
man -k \!
```

Not sure that is what you are really asking?

Comment: Of course, escape the normal way. `\!` is the correct answer.